# CSS Как изменить цвет границы <li> и цвет <a> у visited элемента

Tags: css, css3

```css
.navigation li a:visited {
     border: solid 3px black;
     color: #666;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="pages/todo.html">What to do</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/lessTraveled.html">The road less traveled</a></li>
  <li><a href="where-to-stay.html">Where to stay</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/doNotMiss.html">Not to be missed</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сослаться на родительский `<li>` непосредственно из `a:visited` нельзя.

Проблему можно решить только за счёт форматирования `<li>` как `display: inline` (при необходимости размещения элементов в одну строку) и изменения цвета границы у самого `<a>`. Только гиперссылки предварительно надо сделать `inline-block` или `block` элементами, иначе граница отображаться не будет.